# Sort tuples within list in Haskell

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

So, having scoured the Internet for quite some time for a nice solution, I have arrived at the end of the road.

I am currently faced with a few Haskell problems regarding text-handling, and most of it has been going perfectly fine. However, I am now stuck at sorting tuples within a list.

Basically, I have a list of tuples, so something along the lines of

```
list = [("hey","there"),("there","hey"),("bears","are")]
```

My goal now is to sort the tuples internally so that I receive

```
list = [("hey","there"),("hey","there"),("are","bears")]
```

Which I will then run a `group $ sort list` on to be able to retrieve a tally of how many equivalent pairs there are. In other words, `("hey,"there")`is equivalent to `("there","hey")`.

What I have tried so far is using a map function. However, it seems that you cannot run list operations using the map function, but to at least attempt to understand what my final goal is, here is what I have achieved so far.

```
countup tuples =
    let final =
        sort sorted_internal where
            sorted_internal = map (\x->(sort x)) tuples
    in map (\x->(head x, length x)) final
```

Comment: `Cheerio` typically means goodbye

Comment: Are you basically asking how to sort tuples? You can't sort them generically, they're not lists. Have you considered either not using tuples, or writing `orderTuple :: (a,a) -> (a,a)` which puts the smaller one first if it isn't already

Comment: Alright, how would I implement that into what I already have? Because, yes, my aim is indeed to order them in some way. However, I want to order within the tuples, and not order the tuples themselves.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sort` function can't sort the elements of a tuple; it only works for *lists*.

You have two options. One is to write a function for sorting (2-element) tuples:

```
sortTuple :: (Ord a) => (a,a) -> (a,a)
sortTuple (x,y) = (min x y, max x y)

map sortTuple tuples
```

The other is to use lists instead of tuples:

```
map sort [["hey","there"], ["hey","there"], ["are","bears"]]
```